# Visual Studio Tooltip foreground on Dark Theme

Tags: visual-studio-2010, devexpress, resharper, background-foreground, productivity-power-tools

I recently changed the theme of Windows 7 to *High Contrast Black* and I have some problems with tooltips in Visual Studio, if I click on classes or variables I have a tooltip with foreground black and background black, so I can't read.

[image]

For information I use *Productivity Power Tools* and *Resharper* and *Dev Express*.

I know that in Environment>Fonts and Colors I can edit properties but I don't know which to choose.

Comment: Try `Tools->Options->Environment->Fonts and Colors->Signature Help Tooltip Background`